# Ajax binding kendo asp.net Mvc 3 only json displayed

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

The json result is just being displayed on the screen and not populating the grid.

```
public ActionResult BulkEdit([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{        
    var NewAssets = db.TurnaroundDumps;
    DataSourceResult result = NewAssets.ToDataSourceResult(request)
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then on my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PcInventory_v1_1.Models.TurnaroundDump>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.AssetTag);
    columns.Bound(p => p.SerialNumber);
    columns.Bound(p => p.DeptId);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Location);
})
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax() // Specify that the data source is of ajax type
        .Read(read => read.Action("BulkEdit", "Assets")) 
        // Specify the action method and controller name
    ).Pageable()
)
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: i think its because of a GET request.

Comment: are you using kendo.aspnetmvc.js? 
Also, use the [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] attribute for your action method; avoid JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet as much as possible. 
Don't forget to use kendo.aspnetmvc.js or you'll get only a json returned.

Comment: We solved that in a forum thread. You can link it if you like.

Comment: You should link to the forum post at least for other to use in future instances of this issue.

Comment: Hi, so how was this solved? I have the same problem.. Marius I'm not including kendo.aspnetmvc.js  but I'm including kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js

Comment: I was never actually returning the view . LOL 
`
public ActionResult BulkEdit()
        {
            return View();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot to return the view.

Here is the answer:

```
 public ActionResult BulkEdit()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BulkEdit([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var emp = db.TurnaroundDumps;


        DataSourceResult result = emp.ToDataSourceResult(request);


        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```